Pylance not recognising selenium's class TimeoutException
I am using Visual Studio Code and when I try to import the ConnectionRefusedError from Selenium, I am getting an error. Below is my code snippet
from selenium.common.exceptions import ConnectionRefusedError

Error
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 61] Connection refused

in addition to
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=50166): Max retries exceeded with url: /session/2a50424f26d5dbcb77096e2ed2a0cfc6/url (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x15d878e60>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused'))

I have already tried restarting my IDE, uninstalling Selenium, installing Selenium, clearing my cache and uninstalling pylance as well.

ConnectionRefusedError is not a Selenium exception, it's built into python. See the docs.
